# hp wireless keyboard not working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless-keyboards

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop in HP all in one HP24F0004NS. The mouse works perfectly, but the keyboard works in Bios and it does not work on ubuntu. What can I do, can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same problem

Comment: @M14 You may want to take a look at my new answer.

Comment: mouse is not working for this.Also my wired keyboard is not working after installing this.

Comment: @M14 That's strange. What HP model are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I recently bought a HP Pavilion Wireless Keyboard and Mouse 800 and experienced exactly this problem. I found that there were workaround available for similar problems with Lenovo wireless keyboard + mouse combos manufactured by the same company (Primax). These fixes did not work for me, but I was able to modify one of them to make it work. I have now posted this as a workaround for HP wireless keyboards (although it may also work for other brands):

https://github.com/JohnJohanssonChalmers/hp_wireless_keyboard

Feel free to test it and report your experience.

Comment: Hi @jkej. Thanks for making that utility, really helps me out as I bought an 800 today! One query.. When I enable the service on Ubuntu 18.04, my operating system keeps crashing. Any insight into that?