# Is there any chance to use HP keyboard on Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, usb, keyboard

I have an HP Pavilion Wireless-Keyboard 600, and it's not recognized on Ububtu 16.04. I've found some solutions for Logitech USB keyboards and I can't find something similar for HP. May be you know some way or is it hopeless?...

MfG

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090050/hp-wireless-keyboard-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04#

Comment: I've been using my OLD HP KG-0851 wireless keyboard on my much newer Dell computer both on 16.04 and now on 18.04 w/o a problem.

Comment: @jpezz The comment about older models is totally irrelevant. This specific model as well as others from the same manufacturer (Primax), regardless of the brand, have known issues in Linux and if you cared to read the link above you'd know it needs a driver.